# How to implement segment trees with lazy propagation?

Tags: c, algorithm, data-structures, tree

I have searched on internet about implementation of Segment trees but found nothing when it came to lazy propagation. There were some previous questions on stack overflow but they were focused on solving some particular problems of SPOJ. Though I think this is the best explanation of segment trees with pseudocode but I need to implement it with lazy propagation. I found following links :

http://community.topcoder.com/tc?module=Static&d1=tutorials&d2=lowestCommonAncestor#Segment_Trees

In addition to the above link, some blogs were also there but they all were giving reference to the same thread.

#### Example

An **example** of the application of this data structure would be something like, say I have been given a range of numbers from 1 to n. Now I perform some operations like adding some constant number to a particular range or subtracting some constant number from a particular range. After performing operations I'm supposed to tell the minimum and maximum number in the given number.

An **obvious solution** would be to perform addition or subtraction to each number in the given range one by one. But this can't be feasible in a situation in which no of operations performed are large.

A **better approach** would be using Segment Trees with lazy propagation technique. It says instead of performing the update operation on each number individually, just keep track of all the operations until all operations are done. Then finally perform update operation to get the minimum and maximum number in the range.

**Example with real data**

Suppose I have given the range [1,10] which means numbers are 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10.
Now suppose I perform an operation which decreases the numbers in the range [3,6] by 4 ,so now numbers will look like 1,2,-1,0,1,2,7,8,9,10.
Now I perform another operation which increases the numbers in the range [5,9] by 1, so the number will now look like 1,2,-1,0,2,3,8,9,10,10.

Now if I ask you to tell me the maximum and minimum number then the answer will be :

```
Maximum = 10

Minimum = -1
```

This is just a simple example.The actual problem might contain thousands of such addition/subtraction operations.I hope it's clear now.

This is what I have understood so far but I guess there is no unified link on Internet which explains the concept and implementation in a better way.

Can anyone give some good explanation including pseudocode for lazy propagation in segment trees?

Thanks.

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Lazy propagation almost always includes some kind of sentry-mechanism. You have to verify that the current node doesn't need to be propagated, and this check should be easy and fast. So there are two possibilities:

1. Sacrifice a little bit of memory to save a field in your node, which can be checked very easily
2. Sacrifice a little bit of runtime in order to check whether the node has been propagated and whether its child nodes have to be created.

I sticked myself to the first. It's very simple to check whether a node in a segmented tree should have child nodes (`node->lower_value != node->upper_value`), but you would also have to check whether those child node are already built (`node->left_child, node->right_child`), so I introduced a propagation flag `node->propagated`:

```
typedef struct lazy_segment_node{
  int lower_value;
  int upper_value;

  struct lazy_segment_node * left_child;
  struct lazy_segment_node * right_child;

  unsigned char propagated;
} lazy_segment_node;
```

### Initialization

To initialize a node we call `initialize` with a pointer to the node pointer (or `NULL`) and the desired `upper_value`/`lower_value`:

```
lazy_segment_node * initialize(
    lazy_segment_node ** mem, 
    int lower_value, 
    int upper_value
){
  lazy_segment_node * tmp = NULL;
  if(mem != NULL)
    tmp = *mem;
  if(tmp == NULL)
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(lazy_segment_node));
  if(tmp == NULL)
    return NULL;
  tmp->lower_value = lower_value;
  tmp->upper_value = upper_value;
  tmp->propagated = 0;
  tmp->left_child = NULL;
  tmp->right_child = NULL;
  
  if(mem != NULL)
    *mem = tmp;
  return tmp;
}
```

### Access

So far nothing special has been done. This looks like every other generic node creation method. However, in order to create the actual child nodes and set the propagation flags we can use a function which will return a pointer on the same node, but propagates it if needed:

```
lazy_segment_node * accessErr(lazy_segment_node* node, int * error){
  if(node == NULL){
    if(error != NULL)
      *error = 1;
    return NULL;
  }
  /* if the node has been propagated already return it */
  if(node->propagated)
    return node;

  /* the node doesn't need child nodes, set flag and return */      
  if(node->upper_value == node->lower_value){
    node->propagated = 1;
    return node;
  }

  /* skipping left and right child creation, see code below*/
  return node;
}
```

As you can see, a propagated node will exit the function almost immediately. A not propagated node will instead first check whether it should actually contain child nodes and then create them if needed.

This is actually the lazy-evaluation. You don't create the child nodes until needed. Note that `accessErr` also provides an additional error interface. If you don't need it use `access` instead:

```
lazy_segment_node * access(lazy_segment_node* node){
  return accessErr(node,NULL);
}
```

### Free

In order to free those elements you can use a generic node deallocation algorithm:

```
void free_lazy_segment_tree(lazy_segment_node * root){
  if(root == NULL)
    return;
  free_lazy_segment_tree(root->left_child);
  free_lazy_segment_tree(root->right_child);
  free(root);
}
```

## Complete example

The following example will use the functions described above to create a lazy-evaluated segment tree based on the interval [1,10]. You can see that after the first initialization `test` has no child nodes. By using `access` you actually generate those child nodes and can get their values (if those child nodes exists by the segmented tree's logic):

### Code

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>

typedef struct lazy_segment_node{
  int lower_value;
  int upper_value;
  
  unsigned char propagated;
  
  struct lazy_segment_node * left_child;
  struct lazy_segment_node * right_child;
} lazy_segment_node;

lazy_segment_node * initialize(lazy_segment_node ** mem, int lower_value, int upper_value){
  lazy_segment_node * tmp = NULL;
  if(mem != NULL)
    tmp = *mem;
  if(tmp == NULL)
    tmp = malloc(sizeof(lazy_segment_node));
  if(tmp == NULL)
    return NULL;
  tmp->lower_value = lower_value;
  tmp->upper_value = upper_value;
  tmp->propagated = 0;
  tmp->left_child = NULL;
  tmp->right_child = NULL;
  
  if(mem != NULL)
    *mem = tmp;
  return tmp;
}

lazy_segment_node * accessErr(lazy_segment_node* node, int * error){
  if(node == NULL){
    if(error != NULL)
      *error = 1;
    return NULL;
  }
  if(node->propagated)
    return node;
  
  if(node->upper_value == node->lower_value){
    node->propagated = 1;
    return node;
  }
  node->left_child = initialize(NULL,node->lower_value,(node->lower_value + node->upper_value)/2);
  if(node->left_child == NULL){
    if(error != NULL)
      *error = 2;
    return NULL;
  }
  
  node->right_child = initialize(NULL,(node->lower_value + node->upper_value)/2 + 1,node->upper_value);
  if(node->right_child == NULL){
    free(node->left_child);
    if(error != NULL)
      *error = 3;
    return NULL;
  }  
  node->propagated = 1;
  return node;
}

lazy_segment_node * access(lazy_segment_node* node){
  return accessErr(node,NULL);
}

void free_lazy_segment_tree(lazy_segment_node * root){
  if(root == NULL)
    return;
  free_lazy_segment_tree(root->left_child);
  free_lazy_segment_tree(root->right_child);
  free(root);
}

int main(){
  lazy_segment_node * test = NULL;
  initialize(&test,1,10);
  printf("Lazy evaluation test\n");
  printf("test->lower_value: %i\n",test->lower_value);
  printf("test->upper_value: %i\n",test->upper_value);
  
  printf("\nNode not propagated\n");
  printf("test->left_child: %p\n",test->left_child);
  printf("test->right_child: %p\n",test->right_child);
  
  printf("\nNode propagated with access:\n");
  printf("access(test)->left_child: %p\n",access(test)->left_child);
  printf("access(test)->right_child: %p\n",access(test)->right_child);
  
  printf("\nNode propagated with access, but subchilds are not:\n");
  printf("access(test)->left_child->left_child: %p\n",access(test)->left_child->left_child);
  printf("access(test)->left_child->right_child: %p\n",access(test)->left_child->right_child);
  
  printf("\nCan use access on subchilds:\n");
  printf("access(test->left_child)->left_child: %p\n",access(test->left_child)->left_child);
  printf("access(test->left_child)->right_child: %p\n",access(test->left_child)->right_child);
  
  printf("\nIt's possible to chain:\n");
  printf("access(access(access(test)->right_child)->right_child)->lower_value: %i\n",access(access(access(test)->right_child)->right_child)->lower_value);
  printf("access(access(access(test)->right_child)->right_child)->upper_value: %i\n",access(access(access(test)->right_child)->right_child)->upper_value);
  
  free_lazy_segment_tree(test);
  
  return 0;
}
```

### Result [(ideone)](http://ideone.com/bNVDx)

```
Lazy evaluation test
test->lower_value: 1
test->upper_value: 10

Node not propagated
test->left_child: (nil)
test->right_child: (nil)

Node propagated with access:
access(test)->left_child: 0x948e020
access(test)->right_child: 0x948e038

Node propagated with access, but subchilds are not:
access(test)->left_child->left_child: (nil)
access(test)->left_child->right_child: (nil)

Can use access on subchilds:
access(test->left_child)->left_child: 0x948e050
access(test->left_child)->right_child: 0x948e068

It's possible to chain:
access(access(access(test)->right_child)->right_child)->lower_value: 9
access(access(access(test)->right_child)->right_child)->upper_value: 10
```

Comment: First of all thanks for spending your precious time to answer my question.There are few doubts in my mind which I would like to discuss.First I have studied that we implement segment tree using arrays which are operated just like heap data structure.Secondly,you are saying that we don't create left and right child until needed but in the link which I have given above it says that the entire tree is made at time of initialization only but the information is not propagated to the leaves instantly,they are kept in parent node and propagated only in final step.Please correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: First: Yes. This is currently based on a tree-data-structure instead of an array. You can change this very easily by allocating the memory for all nodes at ones. Second: No, you're right. I thought you were only interested in a lazy propagation of the tree, not the lazy evaluation of an actual query, since this was your title question. Lazy propagation in a tree means that you create the values only if they are needed. You can adapt the same mechanisms described above to create such an effect for an array, however, I doubt that there are values which aren't needed in a query.

Comment: Take a look at my example which I have introduced in my question just now.May be it can give a better picture of my intentions.

Comment: You'll need to post an actual example with actual data. This is still too abstract. I believe I start to understand what you want to achieve, however I never really looked into RMQ. Maybe I'll edit my answer in the following days.

Comment: I have tried to give some more explanation by giving a very common example.Please let me know if it is still unclear.

Comment: @code_hacker: I understand. You want to use lazy evaluation so you don't have to update many fields. I have some approaches, but this is a problem of the discrete mathematics (theoretical computer science) and I'm currently busy with numeric analysis (finite element methods). Could take a while, sorry :/.

Answer (score 2):

if someone's looking for further simple code of lazy propagation without using structures:

(code is self-explanatory)

```
/**
 * In this code we have a very large array called arr, and very large set of operations
 * Operation #1: Increment the elements within range [i, j] with value val
 * Operation #2: Get max element within range [i, j]
 * Build tree: build_tree(1, 0, N-1)
 * Update tree: update_tree(1, 0, N-1, i, j, value)
 * Query tree: query_tree(1, 0, N-1, i, j)
 */

#include<iostream>
#include<algorithm>
using namespace std;

#include<string.h>
#include<math.h> 

#define N 20
#define MAX (1+(1<<6)) // Why? :D
#define inf 0x7fffffff

int arr[N];
int tree[MAX];
int lazy[MAX];

/**
 * Build and init tree
 */
void build_tree(int node, int a, int b) {
    if(a > b) return; // Out of range

    if(a == b) { // Leaf node
            tree[node] = arr[a]; // Init value
        return;
    }

    build_tree(node*2, a, (a+b)/2); // Init left child
    build_tree(node*2+1, 1+(a+b)/2, b); // Init right child

    tree[node] = max(tree[node*2], tree[node*2+1]); // Init root value
}

/**
 * Increment elements within range [i, j] with value value
 */
void update_tree(int node, int a, int b, int i, int j, int value) {

    if(lazy[node] != 0) { // This node needs to be updated
        tree[node] += lazy[node]; // Update it

        if(a != b) {
            lazy[node*2] += lazy[node]; // Mark child as lazy
                lazy[node*2+1] += lazy[node]; // Mark child as lazy
        }

        lazy[node] = 0; // Reset it
    }

    if(a > b || a > j || b < i) // Current segment is not within range [i, j]
        return;

    if(a >= i && b <= j) { // Segment is fully within range
            tree[node] += value;

        if(a != b) { // Not leaf node
            lazy[node*2] += value;
            lazy[node*2+1] += value;
        }

            return;
    }

    update_tree(node*2, a, (a+b)/2, i, j, value); // Updating left child
    update_tree(1+node*2, 1+(a+b)/2, b, i, j, value); // Updating right child

    tree[node] = max(tree[node*2], tree[node*2+1]); // Updating root with max value
}

/**
 * Query tree to get max element value within range [i, j]
 */
int query_tree(int node, int a, int b, int i, int j) {

    if(a > b || a > j || b < i) return -inf; // Out of range

    if(lazy[node] != 0) { // This node needs to be updated
        tree[node] += lazy[node]; // Update it

        if(a != b) {
            lazy[node*2] += lazy[node]; // Mark child as lazy
            lazy[node*2+1] += lazy[node]; // Mark child as lazy
        }

        lazy[node] = 0; // Reset it
    }

    if(a >= i && b <= j) // Current segment is totally within range [i, j]
        return tree[node];

    int q1 = query_tree(node*2, a, (a+b)/2, i, j); // Query left child
    int q2 = query_tree(1+node*2, 1+(a+b)/2, b, i, j); // Query right child

    int res = max(q1, q2); // Return final result

    return res;
}

int main() {
    for(int i = 0; i < N; i++) arr[i] = 1;

    build_tree(1, 0, N-1);

    memset(lazy, 0, sizeof lazy);

    update_tree(1, 0, N-1, 0, 6, 5); // Increment range [0, 6] by 5
    update_tree(1, 0, N-1, 7, 10, 12); // Incremenet range [7, 10] by 12
    update_tree(1, 0, N-1, 10, N-1, 100); // Increment range [10, N-1] by 100

    cout << query_tree(1, 0, N-1, 0, N-1) << endl; // Get max element in range [0, N-1]
}
```

refer this link for more explanation [Segment Trees and lazy propagation](http://se7so.blogspot.in/2012/12/segment-trees-and-lazy-propagation.html)

Comment: Thanks for the blog link.

Answer (score 1):

Although I haven't successfully solved it yet, I believe this problem is much easier than what we think. You probably don't even need to use Segment Tree/Interval Tree... In fact, I tried both ways of implementing `Segment Tree`, one uses tree structure and the other uses array, both solutions got TLE quickly. I have a feeling it could be done using Greedy, but I'm not sure yet. Anyway, if you want to see how things are done using Segment Tree, feel free to study my solution. Note that `max_tree[1]` and `min_tree[1]` are corresponding to `max/min`.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <algorithm>
#include <map>
#include <set>
#include <utility>
#include <stack>
#include <deque>
#include <queue>
#include <fstream>
#include <functional>
#include <numeric>

#include <cstdio>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstring>
#include <cmath>
#include <cassert>

#ifdef _WIN32 || _WIN64
#define getc_unlocked _fgetc_nolock
#endif

using namespace std;

const int MAX_RANGE = 1000000;
const int NIL = -(1 << 29);
int data[MAX_RANGE] = {0};
int min_tree[3 * MAX_RANGE + 1];
int max_tree[3 * MAX_RANGE + 1];
int added_to_interval[3 * MAX_RANGE + 1];

struct node {
    int max_value;
    int min_value;
    int added;
    node *left;
    node *right;
};

node* build_tree(int l, int r, int values[]) {
    node *root = new node;
    root->added = 0;
    if (l > r) {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (l == r) {
        root->max_value = l + 1; // or values[l]
        root->min_value = l + 1; // or values[l]
        root->added = 0;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
        return root;
    }
    else {  
        root->left = build_tree(l, (l + r) / 2, values);
        root->right = build_tree((l + r) / 2 + 1, r, values);
        root->max_value = max(root->left->max_value, root->right->max_value);
        root->min_value = min(root->left->min_value, root->right->min_value);
        root->added = 0;
        return root;
    }
}

node* build_tree(int l, int r) {
    node *root = new node;
    root->added = 0;
    if (l > r) {
        return NULL;
    }
    else if (l == r) {
        root->max_value = l + 1; // or values[l]
        root->min_value = l + 1; // or values[l]
        root->added = 0;
        root->left = NULL;
        root->right = NULL;
        return root;
    }
    else {  
        root->left = build_tree(l, (l + r) / 2);
        root->right = build_tree((l + r) / 2 + 1, r);
        root->max_value = max(root->left->max_value, root->right->max_value);
        root->min_value = min(root->left->min_value, root->right->min_value);
        root->added = 0;
        return root;
    }
}

void update_tree(node* root, int begin, int end, int i, int j, int amount) {
    // out of range
    if (begin > end || begin > j || end < i) {
        return;
    }
    // in update range (i, j)
    else if (i <= begin && end <= j) {
        root->max_value += amount;
        root->min_value += amount;
        root->added += amount;
    }
    else {
        if (root->left == NULL && root->right == NULL) {
            root->max_value = root->max_value + root->added;
            root->min_value = root->min_value + root->added;
        }
        else if (root->right != NULL && root->left == NULL) {
            update_tree(root->right, (begin + end) / 2 + 1, end, i, j, amount);
            root->max_value = root->right->max_value + root->added;
            root->min_value = root->right->min_value + root->added;
        }
        else if (root->left != NULL && root->right == NULL) {
            update_tree(root->left, begin, (begin + end) / 2, i, j, amount);
            root->max_value = root->left->max_value + root->added;
            root->min_value = root->left->min_value + root->added;
        }
        else {
            update_tree(root->right, (begin + end) / 2 + 1, end, i, j, amount);
            update_tree(root->left, begin, (begin + end) / 2, i, j, amount);
            root->max_value = max(root->left->max_value, root->right->max_value) + root->added;
            root->min_value = min(root->left->min_value, root->right->min_value) + root->added;
        }
    }
}

void print_tree(node* root) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        print_tree(root->left);
        cout << "\t(max, min): " << root->max_value << ", " << root->min_value << endl;
        print_tree(root->right);
    }
}

void clean_up(node*& root) {
    if (root != NULL) {
        clean_up(root->left);
        clean_up(root->right);
        delete root;
        root = NULL;
    }
}

void update_bruteforce(int x, int y, int z, int &smallest, int &largest, int data[], int n) {
    for (int i = x; i <= y; ++i) {
        data[i] += z;       
    }

    // update min/max
    smallest = data[0];
    largest = data[0];
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        if (data[i] < smallest) {
            smallest = data[i];
        }

        if (data[i] > largest) {
            largest = data[i];
        }
    }
}

void build_tree_as_array(int position, int left, int right) {
    if (left > right) {
        return;
    }
    else if (left == right) {
        max_tree[position] = left + 1;
        min_tree[position] = left + 1;
        added_to_interval[position] = 0;
        return;
    }
    else {
        build_tree_as_array(position * 2, left, (left + right) / 2);
        build_tree_as_array(position * 2 + 1, (left + right) / 2 + 1, right);
        max_tree[position] = max(max_tree[position * 2], max_tree[position * 2 + 1]);
        min_tree[position] = min(min_tree[position * 2], min_tree[position * 2 + 1]);
    }
}

void update_tree_as_array(int position, int b, int e, int i, int j, int value) {
    if (b > e || b > j || e < i) {
        return;
    }
    else if (i <= b && e <= j) {
        max_tree[position] += value;
        min_tree[position] += value;
        added_to_interval[position] += value;
        return;
    }
    else {
        int left_branch = 2 * position;
        int right_branch = 2 * position + 1;
        // make sure the array is ok
        if (left_branch >= 2 * MAX_RANGE + 1 || right_branch >= 2 * MAX_RANGE + 1) {
            max_tree[position] = max_tree[position] + added_to_interval[position];
            min_tree[position] = min_tree[position] + added_to_interval[position];
            return;
        }
        else if (max_tree[left_branch] == NIL && max_tree[right_branch] == NIL) {
            max_tree[position] = max_tree[position] + added_to_interval[position];
            min_tree[position] = min_tree[position] + added_to_interval[position];
            return;
        }
        else if (max_tree[left_branch] != NIL && max_tree[right_branch] == NIL) {
            update_tree_as_array(left_branch, b , (b + e) / 2 , i, j, value);
            max_tree[position] = max_tree[left_branch] + added_to_interval[position];
            min_tree[position] = min_tree[left_branch] + added_to_interval[position];
        }
        else if (max_tree[right_branch] != NIL && max_tree[left_branch] == NIL) {
            update_tree_as_array(right_branch, (b + e) / 2 + 1 , e , i, j, value);
            max_tree[position] = max_tree[right_branch] + added_to_interval[position];
            min_tree[position] = min_tree[right_branch] + added_to_interval[position];
        }
        else {
            update_tree_as_array(left_branch, b, (b + e) / 2 , i, j, value);
            update_tree_as_array(right_branch, (b + e) / 2 + 1 , e , i, j, value);
            max_tree[position] = max(max_tree[position * 2], max_tree[position * 2 + 1]) + added_to_interval[position]; 
            min_tree[position] = min(min_tree[position * 2], min_tree[position * 2 + 1]) + added_to_interval[position];
        }
    }
}

void show_data(int data[], int n) {
    cout << "[current data]\n";
    for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
        cout << data[i] << ", ";
    }
    cout << endl;
}

inline void input(int* n) {
    char c = 0;
    while (c < 33) {
        c = getc_unlocked(stdin);
    }

    *n = 0;
    while (c > 33) {
        *n = (*n * 10) + c - '0';
        c = getc_unlocked(stdin);
    }
}

void handle_special_case(int m) {
    int type;
    int x;
    int y;
    int added_amount;
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        input(&type);
        input(&x);
        input(&y);
        input(&added_amount);
    }
    printf("0\n");
}

void find_largest_range_use_tree() {
    int n;
    int m;
    int type;
    int x;
    int y;
    int added_amount;

    input(&n);
    input(&m);

    if (n == 1) {
        handle_special_case(m);
        return;
    }

    node *root = build_tree(0, n - 1);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        input(&type);
        input(&x);
        input(&y);
        input(&added_amount);
        if (type == 1) {    
            added_amount *= 1;
        }
        else {
            added_amount *= -1;
        }

        update_tree(root, 0, n - 1, x - 1, y - 1, added_amount);
    }

    printf("%d\n", root->max_value - root->min_value);
}

void find_largest_range_use_array() {
    int n;
    int m;
    int type;
    int x;
    int y;
    int added_amount;

    input(&n);
    input(&m);

    if (n == 1) {
        handle_special_case(m);
        return;
    }

    memset(min_tree, NIL, 3 * sizeof(int) * n + 1);
    memset(max_tree, NIL, 3 * sizeof(int) * n + 1);
    memset(added_to_interval, 0, 3 * sizeof(int) * n + 1);
    build_tree_as_array(1, 0, n - 1);

    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        input(&type);
        input(&x);
        input(&y);
        input(&added_amount);
        if (type == 1) {    
            added_amount *= 1;
        }
        else {
            added_amount *= -1;
        }

        update_tree_as_array(1, 0, n - 1, x - 1, y - 1, added_amount);
    }

    printf("%d\n", max_tree[1] - min_tree[1]);
}

void update_slow(int x, int y, int value) {
    for (int i = x - 1; i < y; ++i) {
        data[i] += value;
    }
}

void find_largest_range_use_common_sense() {
    int n;
    int m;
    int type;
    int x;
    int y;
    int added_amount;

    input(&n);
    input(&m);

    if (n == 1) {
        handle_special_case(m);
        return;
    }

    memset(data, 0, sizeof(int) * n);
    for (int i = 0; i < m; ++i) {
        input(&type);
        input(&x);
        input(&y);
        input(&added_amount);

        if (type == 1) {    
            added_amount *= 1;
        }
        else {
            added_amount *= -1;
        }

        update_slow(x, y, added_amount);
    }

     // update min/max
    int smallest = data[0] + 1;
    int largest = data[0] + 1;
    for (int i = 1; i < n; ++i) {
        if (data[i] + i + 1 < smallest) {
            smallest = data[i] + i + 1;
        }

        if (data[i] + i + 1 > largest) {
            largest = data[i] + i + 1;
        }
    }

    printf("%d\n", largest - smallest); 
}

void inout_range_of_data() {
    int test_cases;
    input(&test_cases);

    while (test_cases--) {
        find_largest_range_use_common_sense();
    }
}

namespace unit_test {
    void test_build_tree() {
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RANGE; ++i) {
            data[i] = i + 1;
        }

        node *root = build_tree(0, MAX_RANGE - 1, data);
        print_tree(root);
    }

    void test_against_brute_force() {
          // arrange
        int number_of_operations = 100;
        for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RANGE; ++i) {
            data[i] = i + 1;
        }

        node *root = build_tree(0, MAX_RANGE - 1, data);

        // print_tree(root);
        // act
        int operation;
        int x;
        int y;
        int added_amount;
        int smallest = 1;
        int largest = MAX_RANGE;

        // assert
        while (number_of_operations--) {
            operation = rand() % 2; 
            x = 1 + rand() % MAX_RANGE;
            y = x + (rand() % (MAX_RANGE - x + 1));
            added_amount = 1 + rand() % MAX_RANGE;
            // cin >> operation >> x >> y >> added_amount;
            if (operation == 1) {
                added_amount *= 1;
            }
            else {
                added_amount *= -1;    
            }

            update_bruteforce(x - 1, y - 1, added_amount, smallest, largest, data, MAX_RANGE);
            update_tree(root, 0, MAX_RANGE - 1, x - 1, y - 1, added_amount);
            assert(largest == root->max_value);
            assert(smallest == root->min_value);
            for (int i = 0; i < MAX_RANGE; ++i) {
                cout << data[i] << ", ";
            }
            cout << endl << endl;
            cout << "correct:\n";
            cout << "\t largest = " << largest << endl;
            cout << "\t smallest = " << smallest << endl;
            cout << "testing:\n";
            cout << "\t largest = " << root->max_value << endl;
            cout << "\t smallest = " << root->min_value << endl;
            cout << "testing:\n";
            cout << "\n------------------------------------------------------------\n";
            cout << "final result: " << largest - smallest << endl;
            cin.get();
        }

        clean_up(root);
    }

    void test_automation() {
          // arrange
        int test_cases;
        int number_of_operations = 100;
        int n;


        test_cases = 10000;
        for (int i = 0; i < test_cases; ++i) {
            n = i + 1;

            int operation;
            int x;
            int y;
            int added_amount;
            int smallest = 1;
            int largest = n;


            // initialize data for brute-force
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                data[i] = i + 1;
            }

            // build tree   
            node *root = build_tree(0, n - 1, data);
            for (int i = 0; i < number_of_operations; ++i) {
                operation = rand() % 2; 
                x = 1 + rand() % n;
                y = x + (rand() % (n - x + 1));
                added_amount = 1 + rand() % n;

                if (operation == 1) {
                    added_amount *= 1;
                }
                else {
                    added_amount *= -1;    
                }

                update_bruteforce(x - 1, y - 1, added_amount, smallest, largest, data, n);
                update_tree(root, 0, n - 1, x - 1, y - 1, added_amount);
                assert(largest == root->max_value);
                assert(smallest == root->min_value);

                cout << endl << endl;
                cout << "For n = " << n << endl;
                cout << ", where data is : \n";
                for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                    cout << data[i] << ", ";
                }
                cout << endl;
                cout << " and query is " << x - 1 << ", " << y - 1 << ", " << added_amount << endl;
                cout << "correct:\n";
                cout << "\t largest = " << largest << endl;
                cout << "\t smallest = " << smallest << endl;
                cout << "testing:\n";
                cout << "\t largest = " << root->max_value << endl;
                cout << "\t smallest = " << root->min_value << endl;
                cout << "\n------------------------------------------------------------\n";
                cout << "final result: " << largest - smallest << endl;
            }

            clean_up(root);
        }

        cout << "DONE............\n";
    }

    void test_tree_as_array() {
          // arrange
        int test_cases;
        int number_of_operations = 100;
        int n;
        test_cases = 1000;
        for (int i = 0; i < test_cases; ++i) {
            n = MAX_RANGE;
            memset(min_tree, NIL, sizeof(min_tree));
            memset(max_tree, NIL, sizeof(max_tree));
            memset(added_to_interval, 0, sizeof(added_to_interval));
            memset(data, 0, sizeof(data));

            int operation;
            int x;
            int y;
            int added_amount;
            int smallest = 1;
            int largest = n;


            // initialize data for brute-force
            for (int i = 0; i < n; ++i) {
                data[i] = i + 1;
            }

            // build tree using array
            build_tree_as_array(1, 0, n - 1);
            for (int i = 0; i < number_of_operations; ++i) {
                operation = rand() % 2; 
                x = 1 + rand() % n;
                y = x + (rand() % (n - x + 1));
                added_amount = 1 + rand() % n;

                if (operation == 1) {
                    added_amount *= 1;
                }
                else {
                    added_amount *= -1;    
                }

                update_bruteforce(x - 1, y - 1, added_amount, smallest, largest, data, n);
                update_tree_as_array(1, 0, n - 1, x - 1, y - 1, added_amount);
                //assert(max_tree[1] == largest);
                //assert(min_tree[1] == smallest);

                cout << endl << endl;
                cout << "For n = " << n << endl;
                // show_data(data, n);
                cout << endl;
                cout << " and query is " << x - 1 << ", " << y - 1 << ", " << added_amount << endl;
                cout << "correct:\n";
                cout << "\t largest = " << largest << endl;
                cout << "\t smallest = " << smallest << endl;
                cout << "testing:\n";
                cout << "\t largest = " << max_tree[1] << endl;
                cout << "\t smallest = " << min_tree[1] << endl;
                cout << "\n------------------------------------------------------------\n";
                cout << "final result: " << largest - smallest << endl;
                cin.get();
            }
        }

        cout << "DONE............\n";
    }
}

int main() {
    // unit_test::test_against_brute_force();
    // unit_test::test_automation();    
    // unit_test::test_tree_as_array();
    inout_range_of_data();

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

There doesn't seem to be any advantage in making the segment trees lazy.  Eventually you will need to look at the ends of each unit slope segment to get the min and max.  So you might as well expand them eagerly.

Rather, just modify the standard segment tree definition.  The intervals in the tree will each have an extra integer `d` stored with them, so we'll write `[d; lo,hi]`.  The tree has the following operations:

```
init(T, hi) // make a segment tree for the interval [0; 1,hi]
split(T, x, d)  // given there exists some interval [e; lo,hi],
                // in T where lo < x <= hi, replace this interval
                // with 2 new ones [e; lo,x-1] and [d; x,hi];
                // if x==lo, then replace with [e+d; lo,hi]
```

Now after initializing we handle the addition of `d` to subinterval `[lo,hi]` with two split operations:

```
split(T, lo, d); split(T, hi+1, -d);
```

The idea here is we are adding `d` to everything at position `lo` and to the right and subtracting it out again for `hi+1` and right.

After the tree is constructed, a single left-to-right pass over the leaves lets us find the values at the ends of unit slope segments of integers.  This is all we need to compute the min and max values.  More formally, if the leaf intervals of the tree are `[d_i; lo_i,hi_i]`, `i=1..n` in left to right order, then we want to compute running difference `D_i = sum{i=1..n} d_i` and then `L_i = lo_i + D_i` and `H_i = hi_i + D_i`.  In the example, we start with `[0; 1,10]` and then split at 4 with d=-4 and 7 with d=+4 to obtain `[0; 1,2] [-4; 3,6] [4; 7,10]`.  Then `L = [1,-1,7]` and `H = [2, 2, 10]`.  So min is -1 and max is 10. This is a trivial example, but it will work in general.

Run time will be O( min (k log N, k^2) ) where N is the maximum initial range value (10 in the example) and k is the number of operations applied.  The k^2 case occurs if you have very bad luck in ordering of splits.  If you randomize the list of operations, the expected time will be O(k min (log N, log k)).

If you are interested, I can code this up for you. But I won't if there is no interest.

Answer (score 0):

Here's the link. It has an implementation and explanation of segment tree with lazy propagation. Although the code is in Java but it won't matter because there are only two functions 'update' and 'query' and both of them are array based. So these functions would work in C and C++ also without any modification.

http://isharemylearning.blogspot.in/2012/08/lazy-propagation-in-segment-tree.html